# 2 Way Communication with Android Phone and PC via Internet

Tags: java, android, udp, tcp

I am trying to control a Remote Control Car with an Andriod Phone from my PC (over 3g internet)

I'm planning on using a ioio (Which is just a board that I can plug into a andriod phone via USB)

The part I am working on now is the communication from my PC to my Andriod App. I've never made Andriod apps before and I'm a amateur C# developer.

At the moment I am planning on communicating via UDP as I can create a UDP server/client in Java easy enough. (http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/)

However I think this may require a public IP address? Which I will not have either on my client or server.

So for simplicty sake, How would you commucicate over the internet between 2 JAVA applications. If you need to stream video from a camera and simple commands.

Comment: you would definitly need a public IP, or atleast get a domain, and deploy your app which can act as a bridge between your PC and the phone.. relaying commands and video.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a public IP, you just need *some* sort of IP with which one device can send packets to the other.  For example, you could connect the phone to your home wifi network, and use the private IPs (typically 192.168.1.x) of the two devices.

If you need the phone to be on 3G, and your PC is behind a NAT router (which is typical), then you'll need to forward a port to your PC — this is a configuration setting on the router — and then have the phone connect to that port on your router's public IP.

Comment: So it wont matter that my IP Address is not public? Its just like remote desktop etc... I cant remote desktop diectly to my home computer because the WAN IP Address is private..

Comment: Your router doesn't have a public IP address on the outside?  It should, unless your ISP is putting all its customers behind NAT, in which case you should get a different ISP.